# Electron | warning: The vm module of Node.js is deprecated in the renderer process and will be remove

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I'm using electron to build my desktop application based on [electron-vite-vue](https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-vue) and I'm keep getting the following warning:

> The vm module of Node.js is deprecated in the renderer process and will be remove

the funny thing is that I'm using ipcRenderer and ipcMain communication so I don't understand why I'm getting this warn.

I'm using electron version:

```
"electron": "^23.1.2",
"electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
```

my index file:

```
import {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu, MenuItem, shell, Tray} from 'electron';
import {release} from 'node:os';
import {join} from 'node:path';
import {Config} from '../common/config';
import {log} from '../utils/logger';
import {registerApis} from './api';

process.env.DIST_ELECTRON = join(__dirname, '..');
process.env.DIST = join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, '../dist');
process.env.PUBLIC = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL ? join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, '../public') : process.env.DIST;

log.info('connect-app is starting');

// Disable GPU Acceleration for Windows 7
if (release().startsWith('6.1')) app.disableHardwareAcceleration();

// Set application name for Windows 10+ notifications
if (process.platform === 'win32') app.setAppUserModelId(app.getName());

if (!app.requestSingleInstanceLock()) {
  app.quit();
  process.exit(0);
}

let win: BrowserWindow | null = null;

const preload = join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js');
const url = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL;
const indexHtml = join(process.env.DIST, 'index.html');

async function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    title: Config.appName,
    icon: join(process.env.PUBLIC, 'icon.ico'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      devTools: true,
    },
    maximizable: false,
  });

  if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    win.loadURL(url);
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    win.loadFile(indexHtml);
  }

  // Test actively push message to the Electron-Renderer
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win?.webContents.send('main-process-message', new Date().toLocaleString());
  });

  // Make all links open with the browser, not with the application
  win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({url}) => {
    if (url.startsWith('https:')) shell.openExternal(url);
    return {action: 'deny'};
  });
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  win = null;
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});

app.on('second-instance', () => {
  if (win != null) {
    // Focus on the main window if the user tried to open another
    if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore();
    win.focus();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  const allWindows = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
  if (allWindows.length > 0) {
    allWindows[0].focus();
  } else {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// New window example arg: new windows url
ipcMain.handle('open-win', (_, arg) => {
  const childWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    childWindow.loadURL(`${url}#${arg}`);
  } else {
    childWindow.loadFile(indexHtml, {hash: arg});
  }

  const tray = new Tray('icon.ico');
  tray.setTitle('Zero Networks Connect');
  tray.setToolTip('Zero Networks Connect');

  const contextMenu = new Menu();
  contextMenu.append(
    new MenuItem({
      label: 'Open',
      click: () => {
        /* Handle open action */
      },
    })
  );
  contextMenu.append(
    new MenuItem({
      label: 'Quit',
      click: () => {
        /* Handle quit action */
      },
    })
  );

  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
});

registerApis();
```

and my implementation of an api is:

```
export const loginChannels = {
  sendChallenge: 'send-challenge',
  verifyChallenge: 'verify-challenge',
  logout: 'logout',
};

export const loginApi = {
  sendChallenge: async (email: string) => {
    return await ipcRenderer.invoke(loginChannels.sendChallenge, {email});
  },
  verifyChallenge: async (email: string, otp: string) => {
    return await ipcRenderer.invoke(loginChannels.verifyChallenge, {email, otp});
  },
  logout: async () => await ipcRenderer.invoke(loginChannels.logout),
};

export function registerLoginApis() {
  log.debug('registering login api');

  ipcMain.handle(loginChannels.sendChallenge, async (event, args): Promise<SendChallengeResponse> => {
    log.trace('handling send challenge request');
    return await loginHandler.sendChallenge(args.email);
  });

  ipcMain.handle(loginChannels.verifyChallenge, async (event, args) => {
    log.trace('handling verify challenge');
    return await loginHandler.verifyChallenge(args.email, args.otp);
  });

  ipcMain.handle(loginChannels.logout, async (event, args) => {
    log.trace('handling logout');
    return await loginHandler.logout();
  });
}
```

any idea what is causing this warning?

Comment: Same problem as you, have you found a solution yet?